# Why I can't compile and install cgminer on my RaspBerry?

Tags: raspbian, software-installation, software-compilation, makefile

I am trying to install **Cgminer** on my RaspBerry (it use RaspBian that is a Debian minimalistic version) as explained here: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=494625.0

In particular the installation steps are these:

```
git clone https://github.com/gridseed/usb-miner/
cd usb-miner/software/cgminer
autoreconf -i
./configure --enable-gridseed
make
```

I have some problem when I try to execute the third step infact when I try to execute the **autoreconf** command I obtain the following error message:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/download/usb-miner/software/cgminer $ autoreconf -i
autom4te: cannot create autom4te.cache: No such file or directory
aclocal: /usr/bin/autom4te failed with exit status: 1
autoreconf: aclocal failed with exit status: 1
```

Why? What can I do to solve this issue?

What exactly do the autoreconf command? and what is the **autom4te.cache**?

Tnx

Comment: are you running all these commands as root? That usually means a directory doesn't exists.. and it can't - or just wont be created.

Comment: yes I runned it using sudo

Comment: Try logging in as root it self. Its long shot but it helped me a few times.

Comment: I will try. What have I to do to log as root by SSH?

Comment: search for rasspberry pi login as root - you will have to set a password then login as root via ssh